# Check if previous Realm Object contains new column

Tags: realm, swift4, realm-migration

I checked online but I can't find much to help me. Basically we're planning to have an "emergency" release of our app due to crashes in the Realm - we forgot to create a migration for a new property.

```
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Pet.className(), {oldObject, newObject in
    newObject?[“nickname”] = nil
}
```

Since this is an "emergency" release some users already have the "nickname" property and if the code above runs this field will be changed to ***nil***. Thus we would like to check if the "nickname" property already exists in the ***oldObject*** so we can retain the value.

**EDIT:** I tried `oldObject?["nickname"] == nil` this works find for those users that already has the *nickname* property. But I encounter *NSException* for the users that doesn't have yet the *nickname* property.

Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found an answer for myself:

```
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Pet.className(), {oldObject, newObject in
    let hasNicknamePropery = oldObject?.objectSchema.properties.contains(where: { $0.name == "nickname" }) ?? false
    if !hasNicknamePropery {
        newObject?[“nickname”] = nil
    }
}
```

I just check the schema of the oldObject and check if the "nickname" property is already exists.